# Fit timeline to first/last frame via python

Tags: python

I'm trying to setup a scene in Blender 2.8 and I'm having problems "fitting" the timeline to the first/last frame.

There's no problem to set the frame-range of the scene via python, but the actual timeline still shows frames 1-250 even if my start/end is 50-100.

In the timeline it seems like you can press View/View All to fit the timeline to only show the scenes actual frame-range. But how do I do this with python? In the tooltip I see a command, but if I execute that command it tells me the context is wrong. So do I change the context to the timeline somehow, or is there another way?

```py
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.frame_start = 50
scene.frame_end = 100

# Does not work
bpy.ops.action.view_all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a custom context, because the operator requires a specific context in which it can be executed. Otherwise the check implemented in its `.poll()` function will return false and execution fails.

You can accomplish this by iterating through the areas to find the timeline (which is now called `DOPESHEET_EDITOR` instead of `TIMELINE` in Blender 2.8). Then you also need the correct region with the type `WINDOW`. Once you have both you can create a custom context.

*This script requires that you have the timeline open as an area somewhere in the UI.*

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.frame_start = 50
scene.frame_end = 100

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                ctx = bpy.context.copy()
                ctx['area'] = area
                ctx['region'] = region
                bpy.ops.action.view_all(ctx)
                break
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. Should I also reset the old context after execution?

Comment: @SimonBjörk The code creates a copy of the current context and only uses the modified one for the operator. There shouldn't be the need to reset any context.